# Array of doubles in scala

Tags: scala

I just want a quick way to create an array (or vector) of doubles that doesn't come out as type `NumericRange`.
Ive tried

`val ys = Array(9. to 1. by -1.)`

But this returns type `Array[scala.collection.immutable.NumericRange[Double]]`

Is there a way to coerce this to regular type `Array[Double]`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
scala> (9d to 1d by -1d).toArray
res0: Array[Double] = Array(9.0, 8.0, 7.0, 6.0, 5.0, 4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0)
```

Comment: By the way, for integers there is also `Array.range(9, 1, -1)` method.

Comment: Two problems : it returns an Array[Int] instead of Array[Double], and the end limit is exclusive. You should use `Array.range(9, 0, -1)`

Answer (score 1):

I think it slightly more concise and readable:

```
Array(9d to 1 by -1 : _*)
res0: Array[Double] = Array(9.0, 8.0, 7.0, 6.0, 5.0, 4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0)
```